# csympy cmake error: Compiler does not support C++11 constructs

Tags: python, c++, c++11, sympy

```
sudo apt-get install cmake libgmp-dev
sudo cmake .
sudo make
```

I attempted to install csympy from gitub using the instructions above.

```
running install
running build
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeCXXInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:4 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:38 (message):
  Compiler does not support C++11 constructs

  CXX11 ERROR LOG :


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/user/Downloads/csympy-master/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/user/Downloads/csympy-master/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 118, in <module>
    'install' : InstallWithCmake,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "setup.py", line 99, in run
    _install.run(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 601, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "setup.py", line 69, in run
    cmake_build()
  File "setup.py", line 39, in cmake_build
    raise EnvironmentError("error calling cmake")
EnvironmentError: error calling cmake
```

However I received the above error during cmake. I checked synaptic that I have gcc-4.8 installed.

```
cmake -std=c++0x .
cmake -std=c++11 .
```

I forced cmake to use the following compilers above, however I received error messages stating that the specified source directories do not exist. What am I missing to compile the csympy cmake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a C++ compiler. To install g++

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

After that you need to clean the repo `git clean -dfx` and run `cmake .` or `python setup.py install` again

Comment: I was able to partially implement your solution, after encountering several issues. I will add a modified version of your solution that I used. I do not have a user defined git, so I was unable to use the git function, but please tell me if I am using it wrong.

Comment: If you do not have git, you can do `rm CMakeCache.txt` instead of the `git clean -dfx` command

Comment: The cmake command must be forced to use g++. This can be done by using cmake -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++ .